# Trying to reach a site from its IP instead of its Domain

Tags: domain

When trying to call a web site from its IP instead of its Domain Name, I get different pages.

I'm not sure what the issue is, but since these are development servers of some client I'm doing work for I was wondering what would cause this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same server can serve multiple websites, and decide which to serve based on the name. In apache multiple sites on the same address are achieved with [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html). Usually the default virtualhost is used when the site is accessed via the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons for this behavior:

- Virtual hosts
- Reverse proxy